# Unable to read Double with Scanner

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I have a strange problem :

if i passed the string "7+4", my call to nextDouble() throw an exception InputMismatchException.

here the complete code :

```
    char ch;
    try {
        ch = getChar();
    }
    catch(EOF e) //On détecte la fin de la chaine
    {
        return new Token(null);
    }

    //Si c'est un chiffre
    if(Character.isDigit(ch))
    {
        pushback(ch);

        //On récupère un nombre
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        Token t = new Token(TokenKind.Number, sc.nextDouble());
        sc.close();

        return t;
    }
```

the getChar method :

```
private char getChar()
{
    try
    {
        //On essaie de lire un charactère.
        int tmp_char = in.read();

        //Si le charctère n'est pas un caractère ASCII, on lève une exception.
        if(Character.charCount(tmp_char) != 1) throw new IllegalCharacterException();
        return Character.toChars(tmp_char)[0];
    }
    catch (IOException e) {throw new EOF();}
}
```

And the pushback(char c)

```
private void pushback(char ch)
{
    try
    {
        in.unread(ch);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException("IOException");}
}
```

And `in` is a PushbackReader initialized with the "7+4" string.

If i call `nextLine()` before `nextDouble()` it returns "4+7".

What i have done wrong ? I actually don't understand...

Comment: Please read the way a `double` value is defined as a string [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so I post the solution if any one else have the problem.

If you want to get the next Double in a string. first call `useDelimiter("")` on your scanner.

EDIT : Not about parsing Double but about Scanner and PushbackReader : They seems that they don't works together... So my tricks is not usefull in my case !